# Why is MSVC __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ 16?

Tags: c++, c++17, memory-alignment

C++ 17 introduces `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` which defines the guaranteed alignment when uses not new-extended `operator new`. However, `std::max_align_t` is 8 which means the maximum alignment of basic types is 8 and `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` over-aligned. My question is why MSVC and other compilers want to over-aligned? Any instruction is being used underlying requires this over-aligned alignment?

Similar question was asked in the following link before:

[Why does the C++ standard allow std::max_align_t and __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ to be inconsistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171482/why-does-the-c-standard-allow-stdmax-align-t-and-stdcpp-default-new-alignm)

However, the comments only mentions that

> "Because types that require 16-byte alignment existed over a decade
> before C++'s default new provided a mechanism to explicitly request
> allocations of such alignments. In order to allow users to use such
> types, Microsoft decided to make their default allocator always return
> 16-byte-aligned pointers."

I am wondering what's the "such types" specifies in detail?

Comment: "*what's the "such types" specifies in detail?*" What do you mean by that? It's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: even function call stacks have been aligned to at least 16 bytes for decades [Why does the Mac ABI require 16-byte stack alignment for x86-32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612443/995714), [Why does the AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391001/995714), [Is the Microsoft Stack always aligned to 16-bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52615235/995714). [Why should data be aligned to 16 bytes for SSE instructions](https://community.intel.com/t5/Software-Tuning-Performance/Why-should-data-be-aligned-to-16-bytes-for-SSE-instructions/m-p/1164004)

Comment: [Why is dynamically allocated memory always 16 bytes aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59098246/995714), [Why is malloc 16 bytes alligned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70692795/995714), [Why is stack frame a multiple of 16 bytes long?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35700491/995714)

Answer (score 1):

MSVC defines `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` to 16 because its `operator new` provides this alignment guarantee.

On MSVC, `operator new` eventually calls [`HeapAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc), and according to the documentation, the alignment of memory returned by `HeapAlloc` is 16 on Win64.

> The alignment of memory returned by `HeapAlloc` is `MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT` in WinNT.h:
>
> ```
> #if defined(_WIN64) || defined(_M_ALPHA)
> #define MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT 16
> #else
> #define MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT 8
> #endif
> ```